# JUnit test a public method impact on non-public fields

Tags: java, junit

In a package are two classes A and B. Each A object has a reference to a B object. The state of a B instance should only be visible by A, meaning all the B attributes have a package visibility. This is due to the A class being too complex - I had split it in two (and it was semantically correct to do so).

The B class has a public method duplicate() performing a kind-of-deep-copy (meaning some attributes are deeply copied recursively, and for some only the reference is copied).

Problem is I need to make test the duplicate method:

- I can call the duplicate method
- I cannot check the state of the newly created object against the state of the original object due to the package visibility
- I would like to avoid creating getters as the state of a B object is not supposed to be visible outside of the package

Is there a way to make the attributes in B visible for testing only?

Comment: Usually the way to test these fields or method is the package or default visibility. Because usually you put the test class in the same package (in a different source folder like src/test/java when your classes A and B are in src/main/java). If you use this project structure you can access the package or default fields from your test class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot check the state of the newly created object against the state of the original object due to the package visibility

Then your test setup is simply wrong.

It is the default best practice in Java unit testing that

- class ProductionA is tested by a class named ProductionATest ... and **more importantly** that
- ProductionA and ProductionATest both live in the **same** package

They should reside in *different* **directories**, but exist in the *same* package!

The typical maven project structure therefore looks like:

```
project-root / src / main / java / my / com / package
```

and

```
project-root / src / test / java / my / com / package
```

When you follow that practice you have no problems getting to package protected fields and methods (and that is exactly why everybody organizes production and test classes in such ways).

Comment: That's fair. The funny thing is that the project use that architecture but my source folder was "src", the files class belonged to the main.java.my.con.package and test.java.my.com.package, leading to my question. The key in your answer was "They should reside in different directories, but exist in the same package." Thank you for your clear and detailed answer!

Comment: @AllirionX You are very welcome, and I appreciate the quick accept!